# Export PDF with fillable textbox from PowerBI

Tags: pdf, powerbi, pdf-generation

I would like to export a PowerBI dashboard to PDF but the PDF should have a fillable form field to enter comments for the PDF recipient.

Is that possible at all? So far, I've only found tips on importing data from fillable PDFs into PowerBI.

Thanks,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.